# given char *arr[n][m] assign (NULL) to arr[i]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

In order to call execve I need to prepare an array of arguments that has a NULL as the last entry. Think argv.
I can say eg.

```
char my_args[3][] = {"MyPath","3" } ;
```

but when I then try to NULL terminate the argument list with

```
my_args[3] = NULL
```

I get error: assignment to expression with array type
Trying for example

```
my_args[3] = (char *)NULL
```

does not work either.
My understanding is that my_args is an array of pointers. I should therefore be able to assign to my_args[i] ;

However the following works, but seems very clumsy:

```
char *args[3];
   char my_argv[2][256] ; 
   strcpy(my_argv[0], "/tmp/DealerServer.exe" );
   snprintf(my_argv[1], 5, "%4d" , 3 ) ;
   args[0] = &my_argv[0][0];
   args[1] = my_argv[1];
   args[3] = NULL ;
```

what is it about char my_argv[3][256] and char *args[3] that is so different?

Comment: `char my_args[3][] = {"MyPath","3" } ;` is not valid C.

Comment: And `my_args[3] = NULL` is nonsense even if `my_args` was a valid array of 3 items. You need to study arrays before using them.

Answer (score 1):

You ask what's different about `char my_argv[3][256]` and `char *args[3]`.  The answer is 'almost everything'.  One is an array of 3 arrays of 256 bytes each; the other is an array of 3 pointers.  One occupies 768 bytes; the other occupies 24 bytes on a 64-bit machine or 12 bytes on a 32-bit machine.

You can't simply assign a null pointer to an array of 256 bytes as `my_argv[2] = NULL;` would try to do.  (Of course, `my_argv[3] = NULL` would assign outside the bounds of the array if the syntax was allowable.)

You might also note that you could not pass the `my_argv` array to `execv()` or `execve()`; the functions expect an array of pointers, not an array of arrays.